# zip a folder from resources using gradle

Tags: gradle

I want to make a gradle task to zip a subdirectory called `pack` from my resources folder, I am not very familiar with gradle, so sorry if this seems like something easy, so far I have this:

```
task genResourcePack(type: Zip) {
    from sourceSets.main.resources
    include '**/*'
    archiveName 'pack.zip'
}
```

this zips my entire resources folder, which I do not want, I also tried doing this as well:

```
task genResourcePack(type: Zip) {
    from sourceSets.main.resources.include('pack/')
    include '**/*'
    archiveName 'pack.zip'
}
```

which is a little better, but then the zip has a folder called pack at the top, and I want to flatten this folder, but not all the way, basically I want the `from` to target the subdirectory of `pack` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found a solution to my problem, but it isn't particularly elegant so I'll keep this open in case someone has a better way. I replaced my from with the following line:

```
from sourceSets.main.resources.getSrcDirs()[0].toPath().resolve('pack')
```